# How can I allow for this code to switch from remote control to autonomous?

Tags: first-robotics, programming-languages, c, robotc

//ERROR: Task 'autonomous' is not defined at global scope level

```
#pragma config(StandardModel, "RVW CLAWBOT")
//*!!Code automatically generated by 'ROBOTC' configuration wizard               !!*//

#pragma DebuggerWindows("joystickSimple")
task autonomous();
task main()

{
while (true)

{


    // update buttons and joysticks
    getJoystickSettings(joystick);

    //Assign the left and right joystick values
    //to the left and right motors
    motor[leftMotor] = joystick.joy1_y1;
    motor[rightMotor] = joystick.joy1_y1;

task autonomous()
  {
    motor[leftMotor] = 80;
    motor[rightMotor] = 80;
    wait1Msec(2500);
    motor[leftMotor] = 0;
    motor[rightMotor] = 0;
    
    wait1Msec(1000);
    
    motor[leftMotor] = 80;
    motor[rightMotor] = -80;
    wait1Msec(2500);
    motor[leftMotor] = 0;
    motor[rightMotor] = 0;
    
  }
    if(motor[rightMotor] == 1) {
    startTask(autonomous);
    stopTask(main);
  
}
}
}
```

Comment: your code is badly formatted ... if you use correct indentation, then you may be able to see your error

Answer (score 2):

The code for “task autonomous()” should be outside of the main() function.